# Find direct video link attribute from Twitter video page in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to access the direct video href/url for an embedded Twitter video? As I looked at the page code it's not written there and the direct .mp4 url seems to contain unique text.

For example this video:

> https://twitter.com/shigaofficial/status/1273207731453702146

The missing video url would be:

> https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1273207566537900032/pu/vid/1280x720/G6JeCs0pl8A638rQ.mp4

What is best way in Selenium to resolve it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate problem with more details like Page HTML, steps to be perform via automation? As its not clear from question.

Answer (score 1):

Use this API URL format to get the Tweet data:

`'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show/1234567890.json?tweet_mode=extended';`

And as a result, you will receive the following JSON:

```json
  "extended_entities": {
    "media": [
      {
        "video_info": {
          "variants": [
            {
              "content_type": "application/x-mpegURL",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1234567890.m3u8"
            },
            {
              "bitrate": 2176000,
              "content_type": "video/mp4",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1234567890.mp4"
            },
            {
              "bitrate": 256000,
              "content_type": "video/mp4",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1234567890.mp4"
            },
            {
              "bitrate": 832000,
              "content_type": "video/mp4",
              "url": "https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1234567890.mp4"
            }
          ]
        },
      }
    ]
  },
```